# Best companion for Mas-Colell Microeconomic Theory textbook

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, mwg

What are the best sources to accompany MasColell Microeconomic Theory textbook in 1st year of MA in economics?

I mean any sources - textbooks, videos, websites, book companions, etc.

And I mean easy sources - as MasColell is quite difficult.

Best if it follows the chapters of MasColell.

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of [Jehle and Reny (2011)](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Microeconomic-Theory-Geoffrey-Jehle/dp/0273731912)? This is a separate textbook for graduate micro theory (i.e. not a companion to MWG). But it covers most of the basic topics in MWG and is supposed to target the master level students (at least in my department).

Comment: Varian Microeconomic analysis is a sort of shorter version of MWG with additional examples for the core of microeconomic theory it’s not a companion but I think the books are complementary. I first learned microeconomic theory from Varian and then again from MWG and I think first being exposed to Varian made studying MWG easier since I already was exposed to the core.

Comment: There are notes to the first chapters of MWG by Huyi Chen available [here](https://github.com/hooyuser/MWG). They might be great for review though not for learning for the first time. The old textbook by Kreps, "A Course in Microeconomic Theory" makes for nice, chatty complementary reading. The newer textbook by Kreps, "Microeconomic Foundations I" is for people who actually want more depth than MWG.

Comment: Thanks gyus for replies. I own Jehly / Reny. I also checked Kreps at amazon. I dont know Varian very much.

Which of these 3 would you recommend me?

Comment: Varian definitely.

Comment: I would go against the grain on the Jehle and Reny; Varian; and Kreps of the world for an MA student. These remain books which are taught axiomatically without much context, or with an assumption that you know the tools of analysis. Look into a book called Chicago Price Theory. Much more readable/suitable for gaining depth as an MA student.

Comment: I checked the book Chicago Price Theory. I did not know about it before. Is it mainstream? I checked it on amazon and it looks interesting.